# Representing using a Matrix Image Set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$T:V->R$, $T$ is a linear transformation. Let $B_V = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \}$. Let $B_R = \{r_1,r_2,r_3 \}$. These are basis for $V$ and $R$.

We have:

$T(v_1)= r_1 + r_2$
$T(v_2)= r_2 + r_3$
$T(v_3)= r_3 + 2r_2 - r_1$
$T(v_4)= r_1 - r_3$

Find the matrix that represents $T$ with respect to the basis $B_V$ and $B_W$.

Attempt:

I am not too sure how to solve it. I know that the matrix will consist of the transpose of the coordinate vectors $T(v_1)$,$T(v_2)$,$T(v_3)$ and $T(v_4)$ with respect to the basis $B_W$.

I got $T=$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, calculate the image of $T$.

When solving this, would I just reduce $T$ to row echelon form and follow the normal method. Or, would I use the fact that im(T) = span{T($v_1$),T($v_2$),T($v_3$),T($v_4$)}? That would mean I would have the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Would either method give me the same answer ? And the same question for calculating the kernel of $T$?

Comment: I don't understand your matrix for the range of $T$$$\text{Im}(T)=Span\left\{(1,1,0)^T,(0,1,1)^T,(-1,2,1)^T,(1,0,-1)^T\right\}=...$$

Comment: @Surb Are you saying that that set is the answer to the range of $T$?

Comment: @Surb Using my first method I reduce $T$ to row echelon form. I managed to get that the basis of the image of $T$ (as I want in the best form) is {(1,-1,0,-1)}. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes to your first question and no to your second one...

Comment: @Surb So in my question, the second method is the correct method to use and not the first method ?

Comment: @Surb Ignore me. I was being really stupid. I'll be back in an hour and resend my working. Please ignore all my previous comments here as I made no sense. Sorry

Comment: @Surb I believe that from my matrix $T$, the image set is just spanned by the columns right ?

Comment: yes (for the first matrix, i.e. the one of $T$).

Comment: @Surb Brilliant. Sorry about the confusion earlier, me being stupid. Just to clarify, my matrix that I calculated to represent the linear transformation $T$ is correct ? I am only asking because then otherwise my subsequent working would be incorrect. Thanks mate.

Comment: yes it's correct (the first matrix is indeed the matrix of $T$, but not the second...)

Comment: @Surb Just what I thought. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Surb For the kernel, would I just row reduce the first matrix and then look for the free variables

Comment: or simply solve the equation $T(v)=0$...